# Norm of a bounded linear fuctional in $C([-1,1])$

Tags: functional-analysis

Fix $\epsilon\in(0,1)$. Let $f:C([-1,1])\to \mathbb{R}$ be a function defined by, $$f(x)=\dfrac{x(\epsilon)+x(-\epsilon)-2x(0)}{\epsilon^2},$$ for all $x\in C([-1,1])$. Find $||f||$.

My attempt:

I have proved that $f$ is a bounded linear functional, most specific, I showed that, $$|f(x)|\leq \dfrac{4}{\epsilon^2}||x||.$$ Thus I was trying to prove that $||f||=\frac{4}{\epsilon^2}$ but I'm not sure. Could you give some idea to find $||f||$? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set $x(t)=0$ for $t\in[(\epsilon+1)/2,1]\cup[-1,-(\epsilon+1)/2]$ and $x(t)=(2/\epsilon)t-1$ for $t\in[0,\epsilon]$ and $x(t)=-(2/\epsilon)t-1$ for $t\in[-\epsilon,0]$ and $x(t)=-2/(1-\epsilon)(t-(\epsilon+1)/2)$ for $t\in[\epsilon,(\epsilon+1)/2]$ and $x(t)=2/(1-\epsilon)(t+(\epsilon+1)/2)$ for $t\in[-(\epsilon+1)/2,-\epsilon]$.

Graphically, they are splines, the highest and lowest points hit $1$ and $-1$ respectively, so $\|x\|=1$ and $x(\epsilon)=x(-\epsilon)=1$ and $x(0)=-1$.

So $\|f\|=\sup_{\|x\|=1}|f(x)|\geq|f(x)|=4/\epsilon^{2}$.

Comment: That is an interesting solution! Thanks a lot! How do you build these splines? Is there a method to do that?

Comment: You really want to have maximized numerator $x(\epsilon)+x(-\epsilon)-2x(0)$ so $x(\epsilon)$ and $x(-\epsilon)$ better to be positive and $x(0)$ negative, but of course you cannot simply put large value to those points because you need $\|x\|\leq 1$, so the maximized is no more than setting $x(\epsilon)=x(-\epsilon)=1$ and $x(0)=-1$.

Comment: But you cannot simply draw some graph with any gap, then it is not continuous, the trick is then to join those peak points with other splines, of course, splines are not the only choice, as long as your graph succeeds to join those peak points then it is done, but it is rather easier to write down the equation of splines than other continuous graphs.

Comment: Thanks, now I understand a little bit better the construction of the function $x$.